# Best way to create higher order functions in sympy?

Tags: sympy

In math, there are functions whose arguments are functions, and whose results are also functions, like derivative and integral.  They're often called [operators.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)) If I have a custom kind of operator, what's the best way to express this in sympy?  By writing a Python class?  Or is there a way in "pure" sympy?

We need an operator for function composition, which isn't commutative.

Update: specifically, I want to compose operators, and have sympy use the normal derivative rules for me.  For example, define `dhat` that takes a function to it's derivative, `xhat` that multiples a function by its argument, then compose `dhat` with `xhat` and apply the product rule:

```
dhat = Operator(diff(f(x), x), f(x))
xhat = Operator(x * f(x), f(x))
dhat.compose(xhat) = identity + xhat * dhat
```

The last line from the product rule:

```
dhat.compose(xhat)(f)(x)
    = dhat(xhat(f))(x)
    = diff(x * f(x), x)
    = f(x) + x * f'(x)
```

Comment: You need to give more detail about what you want to do with the resulting objects.

Comment: How much `sympy` have you studied?  There's a lot there that goes well beyond Python (though it does run in python).

Comment: @hpaulj I'm happy to study whatever `sympy` I need.  I'm proficient in Python and math (at this level), and eager to learn.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin updated question with a specific example, thanks for asking.